# How to make an installer for Android? [To avoid large download]

Tags: android, installation, distribution

I think the question is clear from the title,

1. I have an Android program
2. It needs to read some data from a given path, say SDCARD/myAppData/data which is a large file
3. I think, I should allow users to download this large file while installing the App.
   OR, 
   Say, they can download the file on PC, and then put it in SDCARD, and then the app will read from the SDCARD. (To save bandwidth for the mobile)

I want to provide user a chance to choose a path for SDCARD or system memory..then the installer should install the data into the chosen path... and work.. normally.

Any idea? Please explain...

Comment: "I think the question is clear from the title" -- IMHO, you are mistaken. Nothing of what you describe here fits what I would consider an "installer". As a result, I have no idea what it is you are asking about.

Comment: Agree - not really sure what this has to do with creating an installer. Android handles your install, what you could do is a "first run" action, which might download your file upon first run.

Answer (score 0):

About number '2'... It READS or it WRITES data?

Anyway, what I'd do is displaying a "choose your path" screen depending on a flag (it can be on a SharedPreference or SQLite). The flag will be turned on by default, and will only turn off once the path has been chosen (only then you'll follow the "real" application flow).

This is the closest to an installer I can think about on Android.